# A name/word suggestion for person who travels the world and collects rare items of decor/furniture

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, middle-english

For a project that I am doing, I need a name or word suggestion.

The premise is that a individual is an explorer, or a traveller on adventures to far flung places, and collects & finds unique items. More specifically furniture/decor items.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this question "middle-english"?

Comment: I have tagged as middle-english as I am interested in words that may no longer be common place. I am looking for something rather different. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The word I see most often for this kind of person is "collector." That's not very specific, since the collector could be collecting anything, not necessarily fine decor/furniture. If you want to emphasize that someone really appreciates nice things, you could call him/her an "aesthete," which the OED defines as "A person who professes a special or superior appreciation of what is beautiful." Similar words include "aestheticist," "decorist," and "philocalist."

Since most of these words don't necessarily mean collector, you could use a sentence like this to make the connection:

> Indy was an aesthete collector, searching bustling Marrakeshi markets and abandoned Scottish castles in search of the next great find.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, very concise. Aesthete is not a word I have come across often. Just the kind of thing I am looking for. Really appreciate it. Thank you.